# How to use artifacts of previous job when it was set to manual?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I got a requirement to implement the following using GitLab and I am not sure how to implement it

**Job A:** Compiles and produces artifacts and will be triggered **manually always** but this job is **optional**

**Job B:** Will run independently.  But, sometimes it will use artifacts (not last generated artifacts instead current) of Job A

We need to configure `Job B` in such a way that `had Job A` was executed, `Job B` should use the artifacts of `'Job A'`.  If not `Job B` should run as usual

Kindly let me know if any workaround exists in GitLab to implement this